# Move constructor used in aggregation initialization

Tags: c++, initialization, compiler-optimization, move-semantics

I wonder if the following codes will obtain better performance

```
Obj obj;
obj.a = std::move(...);
...
```

compared to

```
Obj obj = {std::move(...), ...};
```

can compilers be able to do optimization on the codes above?

and which way do you prefer?

Comment: I don't see why it would usually matter, but as usual you need to test it yourself on your specific platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried on http://godbolt.org/ a simple implementation of your code and found that in both cases the compiler was able to do optimization.

I'd prefer the first one if there is no performance difference, simply because initialization lists are overloaded too much. For instance let Obj be a class that has a constructor that takes two integers as arguments. You know std::vector< int > also has a constructor that takes two integers as arguments. But when you give an initialization list {1, 3} to a vector< int >, the two-integer-argument constructor is NOT called! unlike in the Obj case.